# How to derive the Potts model as well as the gauge transformation *directly* from the principle of maximum entropy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, gauge-theory, biophysics

$
\newcommand{\delim}[3]{\left#1#3\right#2}
\newcommand{\delimzero}[3]{#1#3#2}
\newcommand{\delimone}[3]{\bigl#1#3\bigr#2}
\newcommand{\delimtwo}[3]{\Bigl#1#3\Bigr#2}
\newcommand{\delimthree}[3]{\biggl#1#3\biggr#2}
\newcommand{\delimfour}[3]{\Biggl#1#3\Biggr#2}
$Suppose we have a random vector $s = \delim(){s_1, \dotsc, s_N}$ whose each component can be one of integers $\delim\{\}{1, \dotsc, q}$.
In another word, we are considering a system of $N$ Potts spins.
Given $M$ independent samples of the system, we could write the one- and two-site statistics as
$$
\begin{align}
  f_i(a) &= \frac 1 M \sum_{m=1}^M \delta\delim(){a,s_i^m},
\\
  f_{ij}(a,b) &= \frac 1 M \sum_{m=1}^M \delta\delim(){a,s_i^m} \delta\delim(){b,s_j^m}.
\end{align}
$$

I want to derive the functional form the maximum-entropy probability distribution consistent with $\delimone\{\}{f_i}$ and $\delimone\{\}{f_{ij}}$.
The wanted the functional form could be obtained by the optimization problem
$$
\underset{P(s)}{\textrm{arg max}} \sum_s -P(s) \log P(s)
$$
with constraints
$$
\begin{align}
  \textrm{normalization: }
  &\sum_s P(s) = 1,
\\
  \textrm{one-site statistics: }
  &\sum_s P(s) \delta\delim(){a,s_i} = f_i(a) \quad \delim(){1\le i \le N \textrm{ and } 1 \le a \le q},
\\
  \textrm{two-site statistics: }
  &\sum_s P(s) \delta\delim(){a,s_i} \delta\delim(){b,s_j} = f_{ij}(a,b) \quad \delim(){1\le i,j \le N \textrm{ and } 1 \le a,b \le q}.
\end{align}
$$
Since the (Shannon) entropy $S[P] = \sum_{s} -P(s) \log P(s)$ is convex with respect to configuration probabilities $P(s)$, this optimization problem can be solved with Lagrange multipliers:
$$
P(s) = \frac 1 Z \exp\delimthree(){-\sum_i^N h_i(s_i) - \sum_{i<j} J_{ij}(s_i,s_j)}.\tag{1}
$$
where $Z = \sum_s \exp\delim(){-\sum_i h_i(s_i) - \sum_{i<j} J_{ij}(s_i,s_j)}$ is the partition function.
The distribution (1) is also called 'the generalized Potts model'.

There are $q N + q^2 N(N-1)/2$ parameters in eq.~(1).
But constraints except the one ensuring normalization are redundant in the sense that
$$
\sum_{a=1}^q f_i(a) = 1, \qquad \sum_{b=1}^q f_{ij}(a,b) = f_i(a).
$$
Thus the number of independent constraints is $(q-1)N + (q-1)^2 N(N-1)/2$.
And this leads to the so-called gauge invariance such that the distribution (1) is invariant under the transformation
$$
\begin{split}
  J_{ij}(a,b) &\to J_{ij}(a,b) + K_{ij}(a) + K_{ji}(b) ,
\\
  h_i(a) &\to h_i(a) + g_i - \sum_{j \neq i} \delim[]{K_{ij}(a) + K_{ji}(a)} .
\end{split}
\tag{2}
$$
where $\delim\{\}{g_i}$ and $\delim\{\}{K_{ij}(a)}$ are arbitrary constants.
Allow me to explain a bit further: the contribution of $\delim\{\}{g_i}$ is to add an overall constant to the exponent, thus has no impact after normalization; adding $K_{ij}(a)$ to $J_{ij}(a,b)$ and subtracting $K_{ij}(a)$ from $h_i(a)$ simultaneously means to move some contribution of the edge $(i,j)$ to the vertex $i$.

In the literature, the distribution is given first and then the over-parameterization is shown by the gauge transformation.
However, I think the right procedure of the use of the principle of maximum entropy should take the redundancy of constraints from the very beginning and derive the so-called gauge transformation.

So my question is actually:

How to solve optimization problem with redundant constraints while keeping redundancy in constraints?
In another word, how to derive the transformation (2) from redundancy?

This question is raised in the context of applying the principle of maximum entropy to the statistical inference of protein/DNA/RNA sequence data (where each loci has more than 2 possible states and therefore is usually not modeled as an Ising spin).
I add this context in the hope that ​other people confused about this point can be enlightened by answers here.

I have made a somewhat extensive literature survey but failed to find a reasonable derivation for the transformation (2).
Concerning literature I've surveyed, authors either mention the redundancy and soon choose one gauge to eliminate the redundancy, or elaborate a bit further on where the redundancy comes from.
But everyone write down the transformation (2) directly, no one gives a derivation.
I have little knowledge in the gauge theory, does the origin lies there?
Anyway, any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed, this approach is used for analyzing protein structures. I do not understand the question though: you maximize the entropy assuming that constraints are arbitrary (possibly non-redundant), and then show that redundancy leads to gauge invariance...

Comment: I think you are referring the series of works by Weigt and collaborators. See also my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/612999/247642

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, the potential application to protein/DNA/RNA data is implicitly considered in the context. But not only Weigt but also other researchers (e.g., Aurell, Cocco, Monasson, Zecchina) just mention the issue about gauge and did not give a derivation. Since usually regularization is used, there will be no confusion about gauge choice. I understand where the over-parametrization comes from. But I don't know how to derive the transformation from equations of constraints. Namely, I want to have a somewhat rigorous reasoning for the transformation.

Comment: @RogerVadim I am just wondering how to derive the gauge invariance from redundancy, in a somewhat rigorous way.

Comment: I am not really a "gauge" person... but I suppose it means that the constraints are not independent, i.e., there are "constraints on constraints", which means that teh actual number of constraints is smaller than what is put into the maximization procedure.

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, the number of independent 2-site frequencies are only $(q-1)^2$ for each pair. I just do not understand how to get the complete transformation **directly** since I can not write it down directly by simply looking at equations of constraints.